# How can I test the Filereader.onload callback function in Angular/Jasmine?

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, filereader

In the `ngOnInit` of my component I am defining the `Filereader.onload` callback function. I found several solutions that say to mock the filereader and the onload but I think this defeats my purpose to test if the callback is correctly executed when onload is being called.
So I tried to mock the onload Event and then test if the functions inside the callback get called.

```js
it("should import data on filereader onload event", () => {
 const fileReader = new FileReader();
      let loadEvent: ProgressEvent<FileReader>;
     
      spyOn(fileReader, "onload").and.callThrough();

      spyOn(mockServiceOne, "convertData").and.returnValue(
        mockData
      );
      spyOn(mockServiceTwo, "importData").and.callThrough();

      fileReader.onload(loadEvent);
      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(fileReader.result).toBeDefined();

      expect(mockServiceOne.convertData).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(mockServiceTwo.importData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
```

The function I am trying to test is this:

```js
this.fileReader.onload = (event) => {
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(event.target.result.toString());
      const data = this.serviceOne.convertData(
        jsonData
      );
      this.serviceTwo.importData(data);
    };
```

I mocked the two services and methods inside them. But in the test spec they never get called.
However the first assertion that the result of the onload event (`event.target.result`) needs to be defined seems to check true.

Maybe there is a problem with the first line in the function that converts the data to json, since I am not actually giving the function a real file. However when I try to give anything other than the mocked `ProgressEvent` it gives an error.

Please help me with testing the onload callback. Is it correct that I can't mock the filereader onload for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to mock the `FileReader`. I faced this same issue a few days ago. A friend helped me create a workaround by describing the asynchronous nature of the code.

Wrap your code in a `Promise` and call its `resolve()` callback passing the result of the `FileReader`.

```js
// you would load your file here and return the result in a Promise
readFileMethod(file: File): Promise<string> {
      return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (event) => {
                  const jsonData = JSON.parse(event.target.result.toString());
                  const data = this.serviceOne.convertData(jsonData);
                  resolve(data);
            }
            fileReader.readAsText(); // I suppose this is what you called
      });
}
```

Then, your onInit would look something like this:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    let file; // init your file however you do
    this.readFileMethod(file).then((data) => {
        this.serviceTwo.importData(data);
    });
}
```

To test the new method, use `waitForAsync` and `expect()` inside the success callback:

```js
it('should do whatever with the file', waitForAsync(() => {
    component.readFileMethod(file).then((data) => {
        expect(); // your test here
    });
}));
```

To test your onInit, use `fakeAsync()` and `tick()`:

```js
it('should do whatever with the file', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(mockServiceOne, "convertData").and.returnValue(
        mockData
    );
    spyOn(mockServiceTwo, "importData").and.callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(mockServiceOne.convertData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockServiceTwo.importData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```